# Problem in Converting json to class in java ( google custom search)

Tags: java, json, google-custom-search

I am very new to json, google apis. So please guide.
I am trying to write an application in 'JAVA' that would use google custom serch api through Restful. I started learning json and going through [link] http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html i wanted to write some code.

This shows the json of search for google:
http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/reference.html#method_search_cse_list

reference is http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/reference.html

From the reference i found  which fields of this CustomSearch would be String or int or any other data type. They have also defined structure of every object.

But i am facing problems with some data types:

```
items.title     array   The title of the search result, in plain text.
items.snippet   array   The snippet of the search result, in plain text.
items.pagemap   object  Contains pagemap information for this search result.    
items.pagemap.value     array   Pagemap information, keyed by the name of this pagemap.     
items.pagemap.value.value   object  The actual pagemap information.
```

**How would i define them in my class.** what kind of array is title string or char and this pagemap is some convention or any site can give its own tags .

// class CustomSearch

```
public class CustomSearch {
public URL getURL() throws MalformedURLException{
    return url.getURL();
}

@Key ("items") ArrayList<SearchResult> results;
private @Key SearchURL url;
private @Key Query queries;
```

}

// class

```
class SearchResult {
public SearchResult(){        
}

public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}
public String getLink(){
    return link;
}
public String getSnippet(){
    return snippet;
}

private @Key String title;   // is this right ?
private @Key String htmlTitle;
private @Key String link;
private @Key String snippet;   // is this right ?
private @Key String htmlSnippet;
```

}

Comment: What are you using to deserialize the JSON Response?

Comment: I thik i would use Gson.

Comment: @momo Is using any deserializer would make any difference to this question.

Comment: Some deserializer supports deserialization mechanism via annotation (which seems that you are using). For things that I consume from third party webservice, I normally don't rely on auto deserialization via annotation but rather just code to and from JSON myself by walking through the JSON object to get the necessary data.

Comment: @momo That is nice. but before that we need to make a class to store the data. This is my problem. Some thngs in json are not clear. like "array"  what kind of array. and  can string work at that place. and Pagemap as you can see above.

Comment: I see now. Is your question is basically wanting to know the right structure for the class to hold the data? The easiest way to clarify that is to get the actual instance of the data. Combining that with the specs, you should get a clear idea on the structure. Let me give a quick try on that one and see if I could help out

Comment: I've put my observation as an answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I issued a real search using my key as suggested in Google's example:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q=flowers&alt=json
```

And here is what I get (showing just bit of data)

```
items": [
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "FTD.COM - Flowers Online | Roses, Fresh Flowers, Plants and Gift ...",
   "htmlTitle": "FTD.COM - \u003cb\u003eFlowers\u003c/b\u003e Online | Roses, Fresh \u003cb\u003eFlowers\u003c/b\u003e, Plants and Gift \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
   "link": "http://www.ftd.com/",
   "displayLink": "www.ftd.com",
   "snippet": "Aug 2, 2011 ... Order flowers online for same day floral delivery. Shop for flowers, chocolates,   roses, gifts and gift baskets by occasion, season or get beautiful ...",
   "htmlSnippet": "Aug 2, 2011 \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e Order \u003cb\u003eflowers\u003c/b\u003e online for same day floral delivery. Shop for \u003cb\u003eflowers\u003c/b\u003e, chocolates, \u003cbr\u003e  roses, gifts and gift baskets by occasion, season or get beautiful \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
   "cacheId": "D_MQAIEeVpAJ",
   "pagemap": {
    "metatags": [
     {
      "y_key": "e887dc108fef83f6",
      "msvalidate.01": "71957E1C9D33211154243270EB14C63C"
     }
    ]
   }
  ......
```

It looks like:

```
items.title     array   The title of the search result, in plain text.
```

This looks like a String datatype from bunch of results that I get, so I am not sure why the reference classified it as array

```
items.snippet   array   The snippet of the search result, in plain text.
```

This looks like a String datatype as well from the results that I got

```
items.pagemap   object  Contains pagemap information for this search result.    
items.pagemap.value     array   Pagemap information, keyed by the name of this pagemap.     
items.pagemap.value.value   object  The actual pagemap information.
```

Based on the [PageMap description](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/structured_data.html#pagemaps) this looks like an arbitrary key-value pair data that the website could provide.

Below are some of pagemaps that I get from my test for your reference:

```
 "pagemap": {
    "metatags": [
     {
      "y_key": "e887dc108fef83f6",
      "msvalidate.01": "71957E1C9D33211154243270EB14C63C"
     }
    ]
   }

 "pagemap": {
    "website": [
     {
      "type": "website",
      "title": "ProFlowers",
      "description": "The freshest flowers, guaranteed to last at least 7 days.",
      "image": "http://a1128.g.akamai.net/7/1128/497/0001/images.proflowers.com/pcsite/ProflowersLogo_nb.gif",
      "url": "http://www.proflowers.com/",
      "site_name": "ProFlowers",
      "app_id": "180475245301608"
     }
    ],
    "metatags": [
     {
      "msnbot": "NOODP",
      "msvalidate.01": "77940E049C181974C3AA656C72688B4C"
     }
    ]
   }

  "pagemap": {
    "metatags": [
     {
      "viewport": "width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;"
     }
    ]
```

As pagemap is very unstructured I would store them as `Map<String, JSONObject> pagemap`. As you can see that I just keep the original JSONObject in pagemap so in case if you need it, you could always extract it. Unless there is a set of definitions what type we could put in pagemap along with its fields, representing the value of the pagemap as a Class could be difficult.